# iptables: command not found - CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables

I am using CentOS 5.5. I want to add new IP in my iptables. But I cannot do it.

Tried everything with 'iptables'. The latest version of 'iptables' is at sbin. I'm in 'sbin' directory. But it says "iptables: command not found". What shall I do now?

Comment: Can you please format your question in a readable way.

Comment: And elaborate.  Because just the output of `ls` isn't a question.

Comment: First off, check if it's really there and not just a busted symlink: `ls -lsa /usr/sbin/iptables`

Comment: What is the output of  `ls -l /usr/sbin/iptables` ? And what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) remove the `ls` output and replace it with `ls -l iptables`, that's all we need; ii) tell us _which_ `sbin` directory that is in. Is it `/usr/sbin`? `/sbin`? `/usr/local/sbin`? iii) show us the output of `echo $PATH` run as root. Finally, you seem to be logged in as `root`, why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: Dear @Shadur

The output of "ls -lsa /usr/sbin/iptables" is as below:
[root@104 /]# ls -lsa /usr/sbin/iptables
ls: /usr/sbin/iptables: No such file or directory
[root@104 /]# ls -lsa sbin/iptables
68 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60920 Nov  2  2009 sbin/iptables

Comment: Dear @Thomas-Erker

The output of "ls -l /usr/sbin/iptables" is as below:
[root@104 /]# ls -l /usr/sbin/iptables
ls: /usr/sbin/iptables: No such file or directory
[root@104 /]# ls -l /sbin/iptables
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60920 Nov  2  2009 /sbin/iptables

Comment: Dear  @terdon

The output of "ls -l iptables" is as below:
[root@104 /]# ls -l iptables
ls: iptables: No such file or directory

iptables is at /sbin. If I type "whereis iptables" it shows:
[root@104 /]# whereis iptables
iptables: /sbin/iptables /usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz

The output of "echo $PATH" is as below:
[root@104 /]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Comment: @eMythMakers.com: Please add relevant information to your question, nat as a comment.

Comment: @Thomas-Erker
I want to insert a new IP in my IPTables. But it is not working. Can anybody give me any idea what I have to do now? The command is as below:
[root@104 /]# iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.100 -j ACCEPT
bash: iptables: command not found

Comment: @eMythMakers.com: STOP abusing comments for relevant information that belongs to the question. EDIT your question.

Comment: Ok, may be I am new in StackExchange.com. But my problem is I want to insert an IP into my iptables. What I can do now?

Comment: First of all, for the love of $DEITY edit your original question, get rid of the full `ls` output and replace it with the output of `ls -lsa /usr/sbin/iptables` , `which iptables`, and `echo $PATH`. We really don't need the full directory output.

Comment: Done.. And have rewrite the question.

Comment: The **exact** output, not a summary. If anything, your question is now even *more* uninformative than it was before.

Answer (score 1):

Your iptables program is at `/sbin/iptables`, but `/sbin/` is not in your `PATH`. Even if you go to `/sbin/` directory and type `iptables`, your command prompt will say `iptables: Command not found`. That is because your command prompt will look in `PATH` directories and try to find `iptables` there. However, current directory (`/sbin/` in your case) is not in your `PATH` either.

For CentOS5 `/sbin/` is not in PATH by default. You are allowed to run `iptables` only as root, but, if you switch to root by typing

```
su
```

`/sbin/` will not be in your `PATH`. On the other hand, if you switch to root with

```
su -
```

`/sbin/` will be in your `PATH`and typing only `iptables` will find your iptables in `/sbin/` directory. If you want to be sure `iptables` are found every time, always type

```
/sbin/iptables
```

In that way, it does not matter what is in your `PATH` as you will specify full pathname to your program and it will always be found.

Comment: Also, "." is not in the path, for very good security reasons. (OP said they are inside `/sbin`.)

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS5, the iptables configuration file is `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.  Edit that file, and restart the firewall with `/sbin/service iptables restart`.